# How to GET this value from JSON from Twitter API

Tags: php, json, api, twitter, get

Hey guys,
feel stupid for asking this question but I'm stuck and new with getting values from JSON. 
In the JSON example of the statuses/mentions of the Twitter API: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/mentions

I'm trying to get the 'screen_name' value from with the 'user' directory/array piece (don't know the term). Heres what I'm using to pull values currently:

```
$lastmentions = $oauth->get('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/mentions.json');
$lastmentionsuser = $lastmentions[0]->user;
```

Thanks guys, Dex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$screen_name = $lastmentionsuser->screen_name;
```

Comment: no joy :S Should I specify something like user['screen_name']; ?

Comment: `['screen_name']` is for arrays and `->sreen_name` is for objects. Assuming you correctly set $lastmentionsuser to a user object with `$lastmentions[0]->user` then `$lastmentionsuser->screen_name`. If you are unsure of the structure of your data you can view it formated nicely using `echo '<pre>'; print_r($lastmentions);`

Answer (score 0):

Woop Woop figured it!
It was:

```
$lastmmentionsuser = $lastmmentions[$i]->user->screen_name;
```